# I am trying to find all rows that have values between 0-500, 500-5000, 5000-35000, 35000-65000, >60000

Tags: python, pandas, csv, dataframe

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('/Users/gfidarov/Desktop/daylite/export_daylite_v0.2.csv')
#print(df)
df1 = df[df['Итог'] >'60000']
a = len(df1)
df5 = df[df['Итог'].isin(['40565', '60000'])]
f = len(df5)
df2 = df[df['Итог'].isin(['5000', '35000'])]
b = len(df2)
df3 = df[df['Итог'].isin(['500', '5000'])]
c = len(df3)
df4 = df[df['Итог'].isin(['0', '500'])]
d = len(df4)
#print(df2)
print(a)    # >60000
print(b)    # 5000- 35000
print(c)    # 500 - 5000
print(d)    # 0 - 500
print(f)    # 35000 - 60000
```

My code works fine in gives me some values but for example in my csv I have some values between 35000-65000. Somehow the output from that list is zero that means my code can't see those values.

My values type looks like this

```
44300
23400
4050
31230
12
45333
12341
64500
3430
13
95844
```

```
330
2
32
78
0
```

Thats the output that I get.

Comment: I think that  .isin function is wrong for that situation but I can find another one that can read all values

Comment: You need to convert `df['Итог']` to an integer `dtype`: `df['Итог'] = df['Итог'].astype(int)`. Then you need to use [`between`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.between.html) and get rid of the other strings

Comment: Have a look into the [`pandas.cut`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.cut.html) function which enables the **binning** of data.

Comment: okay let me try both methods.

Comment: `df['Итог'] = df['Итог'].astype(int)` will fail for rows like `,,,`. What do you want to do with those rows? EDIT: Actually, just drop the conversion to `int` altogether sorry. Just swap `isin` to `between`. Lexicographic ordering will naturally avoid the issue

Comment: @roganjosh sorry I am bit confused with your answer. Please can you write it as an answer so I can understand it better

Comment: @roganjosh I just want to ignore them I need only values.

Comment: @roganjosh I am getting this error when change isin to between 

'>=' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'

Comment: I am putting together an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When your reading cvs you can convert the column to an int

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('/Users/gfidarov/Desktop/daylite/export_daylite_v0.2.csv')
df = df[pd.to_numeric(df['Итог'], errors='coerce').notnull()]
```

Then all mathematical operations will work as expected

```
#print(df)
df1 = df[df['Итог'] > 60000]

df5 = df[df['Итог'].between(40565, 60000)]

df2 = df[df['Итог'].between(5000, 35000)]

df3 = df[df['Итог'].between(500, 5000)]

df4 = df[df['Итог'].between([0, 500)]
```

Comment: ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '-'

Comment: import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("/Users/gfidarov/Desktop/daylite/export_daylite_v0.2.csv", converters={"Итог": int()})
df5 = df[df['Итог'].between(35000, 60000)]
print(df5)


I did everything good, but still getting an error

**TypeError: '>=' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'**

Comment: can you drop those rows that aren't fully numeric `10:`?

Comment: YES I did that you was right the problem was in those rows I dropped them and it works now thank you a lot

Answer (score 0):

You could consider using `pd.cut` as following

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

lst = [44300, 23400, 4050, 31230, 12, 45333,
       12341, 64500, 3430, 13, 95844, 330, 2,
       32, 78, 0]
df = pd.DataFrame({"a":lst})

bins = [0, 500, 5000, 35000, 60000, np.infty]
df["bins"] = pd.cut(df["a"], bins)

df.groupby("bins").size()

bins
(0.0, 500.0]          6
(500.0, 5000.0]       2
(5000.0, 35000.0]     3
(35000.0, 60000.0]    2
(60000.0, inf]        2
```

Comment: this one works but not for csv ((( the problem is to convert my csv string list into the integer.

Comment: Have you considered to convert to float instead of int?

Comment: yes I did but still getting the error like this one **TypeError: '>=' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'**

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('/Users/gfidarov/Desktop/daylite/export_daylite_v0.2.csv')
df = df[pd.to_numeric(df['Итог'], errors='coerce').notnull()]

df1 = df[df['Итог'] > 60000]
a = len(df1)
df2 = df[df['Итог'].between(40565, 60000)]
b = len(df2)
df3 = df[df['Итог'].between(5000, 35000)]
c = len(df3)
df4 = df[df['Итог'].between(500, 5000)]
d = len(df4)
df5 = df[df['Итог'].between(0, 500)]
f = len(df5)

print(a)
print(b)
print(c)
print(d)
print(f)
print(a+b+c+d+f)
```

output[]

```
22
15
585
570
326
1518
```